# SSRS Blank page when open url

Tags: reporting-services

[image]

Just installed the SSRS. I open link from configuration and get the page without the controls or anything.
How to fix this issue?

**UPDATE:**
When I try to access SSRS via SSMS I get an error
[image]

Maybe it was installed in a wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

you're using the wrong url
you need to use the reportmanager url

https://[ComputerName]/reports

you can find the specific url you need to use in the configuration manager
[image: configuration manager]

Comment: But it is my computer name :( Besides this url is configured in the Reporting Services Configuration Manager

Comment: a reportserver has 2 urls, the sever url and the manager url, you are using the api url, and webinterface is behind the manager url. just replace reportserver with reports

Comment: If you mean replace like "http://myakhyayev:8080/reports/" then IE says webpage not  found

Comment: your specific url may differ depending on your settings, or be case sensitive

Comment: I can't connect to the Reporting Services Configuration manager - report servers not found

I only can connect to the Report Server Configuration Manager but both of them don't have Report Manager URL tab :(

Comment: preferabely the one installed with your sql server instance